# Como redirecionar uma site para outro mantendo o restante do url

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um site **meusite.net**, mas migrei para o domínio **meusite.com.br**. Porém o google já indexou as mais de 2000 páginas que tenho no meusite.net. Pra resolver esse problema eu criei outra página pra usar o domínio meusite.net com o seguinte código de redirecionamento:

```
<script>
  location.href="https://www.meusite.com.br/";
</script>
```

Mas esse código não resolve totalmente porque redireciona todas as páginas indexadas para meusite.com.br e eu quero que por exemplo, no link **meusite.net**/contato.html ele mude automaticamente para **meusite.com.br**/contato.html. Mantendo o restante do url.

Comment: tentou pegar a url antes? `var url =  "https://www.meusite.com.br/" location.href= url + 'contato.html' `?

Comment: Eu havia postado uma resposta com um código de redirecionamento `var url = location.href.split("/"); location.href = "https://meusite.com.br/"+url.pop();`, mas como não sei como o Google irá tratar as páginas indexadas com esse redirecionamento, preferi excluir a resposta.

Comment: Eu testei. Porem acontece isso: a página indexada meusite.net/licenca/gratuito.html redireciona para meusite.com.br/gratuito.html. Então dá erro 404 pois não é o link completo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia usar método replace.
Exemplo:

```js
var url = location.href;
location.href = url.replace("meusite.net","meusite.com.br");
```

Espero te ajudando.

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigado. Era isso mesmo.